# Determining a space of differentiability

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, function-spaces

I have a questions and maybe you are able to assist with this? Let us consider the space $X:=\mathrm{L}^2[0,\pi]$. On $X$ we consider the family of operators $(P(t,s))_{t\geq s}$ defined by
$$
P(t,s)f:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{u_n(t,s)\left\langle f,e_n\right\rangle e_n},
$$
where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis for $X$. Moreover, the functions $u_n$ are supposed to be the solutions of the initial value problem given by
$$
\begin{cases}
u''(t)+n^2\alpha(t)u(t)=0,&\quad 0\leq s\leq t\leq \pi,\\
u(s)=0,&\\
u'(s)=1.&
\end{cases}
$$
Here $\alpha$ is a continuous differentiable function with $\alpha(t)\geq1$. The question now is, how to determine the following space explicitly:
$$
\mathscr{D}_2:=\{f\in X:\ (t,s)\mapsto P(t,s)f\ \text{is twice continuously differentiable}\}.
$$
I tried to differentate entrywise, but I do not think that this is allowed without any saying. Is it maybe possible to describe $\mathscr{D}_2$ by means of well-know function spaces within $X$?

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by differentiable? Is it with respect to $s$ and $t$, or something else?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Good question. I mean that all partial derivatives exist. Does this help?

Comment: Which $\frac{\partial}{\partial ?}$ derivatives? The ambiguity is that in addition to $s$ and $t$ you can also differentiate along your spatial coordinate in $X=L^2[0,\pi]$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I talk about $\frac{\partial}{\partial{s}}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}$ as well as $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{s}\partial{t}}$, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial{s}^2}$, etc.